# BFG Repo cleaner - Moving git history of a directory from repository A to repository B

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have two repositories viz. repository A and repository B. I am moving one directory from repository A viz. dir-to-move to repository B. But I want to retain git history of that directory only ( i.e. of dir-to-move ) for which git-filter-branch is taking huge time. So I want to use BFG Repo cleaner which is faster. But I want to reduce size of my .git folder as well. So question is two fold

1. How do I execute following command using BFG Repo cleaner ?

git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter **{dir-to-move}** -- --all

2. How to reduce .git size after running BFG Repo cleaner ?( which is right now in GB to MB )

Answer (score 0):

> How do I execute following command using BFG Repo cleaner ?
>
> `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter {dir-to-move} -- --all`

Answer received to the BFG issue [Equivalent of git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/303#issuecomment-442374644) addresses your question:

> There is no such feature in BFG - you would have to add one yourself
>   if you needed this.
>
> The main barrier is - the way BFG currently works, it is unconcerned
>   with specific paths of blobs in the repo. It just visits all commits,
>   then recursively processes each commit's trees and subtrees. As it
>   does so it does not keep any track of the "directory" position of the
>   current subtree it is processing, so there's no support for any
>   features which work with full paths.

Comment: Thanks for clarification !